# Отменить перенаправление на страницу контроллера

Tags: php

Необходимо вызвать `action_addtocart` в контроллере `cart` без перенаправления на страницу этого контроллера. Т.е. есть сайт, например, `site.ru` в `main_view` есть кнопка "Купить", и ссылка `cart/addtocart + определенный id товара`. Со страницы, например, `site.ru/product/details/8` эта кнопка работает правильно, а со стартовой страницы перенаправляет на страницу `site.ru/cart/addtocart`. Надеюсь понятно объяснил. У меня есть подозрения что это связанно с роутами, так что привожу код:

```
 // контроллер и действие по умолчанию
    $controller_name = 'Main';
    $action_name = 'index';
    $params=[];

    $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    // получаем имя контроллера
    if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
    {
        $controller_name = $routes[1];
    }

    // получаем имя экшена
    if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
    {

        $action_name = $routes[2];

    }
    if ( isset($routes[3]) ) {
        $params = array_slice($routes, 2);
    }

    // добавляем префиксы
    $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
    $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
    $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;

    // подцепляем файл с классом модели

    $model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';
    $model_path = "application/models/".$model_file;
    if(file_exists($model_path))
    {
        include "application/models/".$model_file;
    }

    // подцепляем файл с классом контроллера
    $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
    $controller_path = "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
    if(file_exists($controller_path))
    {
        include "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
    }
    else
    {

        //Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

    // создаем контроллер
    $controller = new $controller_name;
    $action = $action_name;

    if(method_exists($controller, $action))
    {
        // вызываем действие контроллера
        $controller->$action($params);
    }
    else
    {

        //Route::ErrorPage404();
    }
```

Если нужен другой кусок кода, напишите, добавлю к вопросу. Не добавляю сразу т.к. не знаю в чем конкретно может быть причина, а приводить код отовсюду подряд считаю не разумным.

Answer (score 1):

> Со страницы, например, site.ru/product/details/8 эта кнопка работает правильно, а со стартовой страницы перенаправляет на страницу site.ru/cart/addtocart

А куда вы хотите чтобы вас перенаправляла эта кнопка с главной страницы?...На главной странице эта кнопка вас перенавравляет на site.ru/cart/addtocart - все верно ведь эта кнопка "Купить товар", на главнйо странице Id товар в URL не задан, соответсвенно этой кнопки там быть не должно, просто уберите эту кнопку с главной страницы....

Если всеже у вас на главной странице отображаюься различные товары с такими кнопками, то просто сделайте чтобы в кнопку попадал Id товара, тогда будет работать корректно.

Comment: id товара попадает. я же говорю, кнопки идентичны что там что там, и следовательно ссылки на экшэны тоже: `<a href="/cart/addtocart" id="add-to-cart" data-id="<?php echo $productItem["ProductID"];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-outline">+<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Купить </a>`

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос зачем нужна эта кнопка на главной?....как вы определили что ссылки идентичны?....на главной $productItem["ProductID"] - у вас не задан на главной но задан на внутренних страницах, потому ссылка не совсем идентичная

Comment: у меня на главной грид продуктов, поэтому она там нужна и ProductID тоже задан, так как я этот грид заполняю циклом из БД.

Comment: НЕвидя кода сложно понять......у вас код доступен по какойто ссылке..чтобы можно было перейти посмотреть на сайт и на главную и внутреннюю страницу?.....Наверно дело в роутах.......проверяйте роуты и js события......возможно переход по ссылке не срабатывает и перехватывается js.....если ссылки идентичны то вы не можете просто так попасть на другую страницу !